# two image slider in single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi friends am trying to create two image slider in single page using jquery but some problems are felt during running this file in browser.
Here is my code

html

```
<div id="projects">
    <div id="completed">
    <div class="button-previous">prev</div>
        <div class="button-next">next</div>
     <div class="slider-wrapper">

            <div class="slider">
          <div class="sp" style="background: blue;">akjdfalfkdj</div>
          <div class="sp" style="background: yellow;">akjdfautlfkdkjkhkj</div>
          <div class="sp" style="background: green;" >akjdfalfkdiyukjkhkj</div>
      <div class="sp" style="background: red;">akjdfalfkdkkljjkhkj</div>
            </div>
          </div>



     </div>
     <div id="notcompleted">
         <div class="button-previous-notcmpt">prev</div>
         <div class="button-next-notcmpt">next</div>
     <div class="slider-wrapper">

            <div class="slider">
          <div class="sp-notcmpt" style="background: blue;">akjdfalfkdj</div>
      <div class="sp-notcmpt" style="background: yellow;">akjdfautlfkdkjkhkj</div>
     <div class="sp-notcmpt" style="background: green;" >akjdfalfkdiyukjkhkj</div>
     <div class="sp-notcmpt" style="background: red;">akjdfalfkdkkljjkhkj</div>
            </div>
           </div>

       </div>
```

...........................................................................................

css

```
    .slider-wrapper 
         {width:300px; height:250px;margin:15px;margin-left:25px  }
    .slider 
       {width:225px; height:225px; position:relative;}
  .sp 
  {width:250px; height:250px; position:absolute;}


  .button-previous 
     {margin-top:120px;float:left;}
  .button-next
      {margin-top:120px;float:right;}
   .button-previous-notcmpt
   {margin-top:120px;float:left}
  .button-next-notcmpt 
      {margin-top:120px;float:right;}
   .sp-notcmpt 
       {width:250px; height:250px; position:absolute;}
   div#completed{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    border: solid black 1px;
    overflow: hidden;


   } 
    div#notcompleted{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    border: solid black 1px;

    }

    div#recentprojects{
    height: 35px;
    border: dotted green 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0e3e6e;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial,normal;
    line-height: 33px;
   }
```

script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#completed')){
            $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
           $('.sp').hide();    
           $('.active').show();

    $('.button-next').click(function(){

    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('.button-previous').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
    });
    }
    if($('#notcompleted')){
       $('.sp-notcmpt').first().addClass('active');
       $('.sp-notcmpt').hide();    
       $('.active').show();
    $('.button-next-notcmpt').click(function(){

    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.sp-notcmpt').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp-notcmpt').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('.button-previous-notcmpt').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.sp-notcmpt').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp-notcmpt').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
    });
    }

});
```

Comment: pleas help me to find my error in code

Comment: Can you please clarify ,what problems you felt?

Comment: What console error is there in browser?

Comment: There are no console errors.now tell what is required by the code.

Comment: images in both sliders slides in single click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the script.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#completed')){
            $('#completed .sp').first().addClass('active');
           $('#completed .sp').hide();    
           $('#completed .active').show();

    $('#completed .button-next').click(function(){

    $('#completed .active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('#completed .oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('#completed .sp').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('#completed .oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('#completed .oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('#completed .sp').fadeOut();
    $('#completed .active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('#completed .button-previous').click(function(){
    $('#completed .active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('#completed .oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('#completed .sp').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('#completed .oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('#completed .oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('#completed .sp').fadeOut();
    $('#completed .active').fadeIn();
    });
    }

    if($('#notcompleted')){
       $('#notcompleted .sp-notcmpt').first().addClass('active');
       $('#notcompleted .sp-notcmpt').hide();    
       $('#notcompleted .active').show();
    $('#notcompleted .button-next-notcmpt').click(function(){

    $('#notcompleted .active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('#notcompleted .oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('#notcompleted .sp-notcmpt').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('#notcompleted .oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('#notcompleted .oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('#notcompleted .sp-notcmpt').fadeOut();
    $('#notcompleted .active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('#notcompleted .button-previous-notcmpt').click(function(){
    $('#notcompleted .active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('#notcompleted .oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('#notcompleted .sp-notcmpt').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('#notcompleted .oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('#notcompleted .oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('#notcompleted .sp-notcmpt').fadeOut();
    $('#notcompleted .active').fadeIn();
    });
    }

});
```

Also check, you have included the jquery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @mirajrjaee ,is answer correct? if yes then please accept as Correct answer and do +1 vote.

Comment: @ Pratik Joshi  the answer was correct.Thank you ,i dont have enough reputation for vote your answer.I have just started with stakoverflow ...thank you

Comment: @mirajrjaee you are welcome. You can accept the answer as correct by click on the tick mark left side